# How to validate json correctly

Tags: arrays, json, codeception

I have such response from api call:

```
[{
    "1": {
        "name": "Euro",
        "iso": "EUR",
        "sign": "€"
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Dollar",
        "iso": "USD",
        "sign": "$"
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "Pound",
        "iso": "GBP",
        "sign": "£"
    },
    "6": {
        "name": "Czech koruna",
        "iso": "CZK",
        "sign": "Kč"
    },
    "7": {
        "name": "Australian Dollar",
        "iso": "AUD",
        "sign": "A$"
    }, ...
]
```

and I use seeResponseMatchesJsonType() method to validate this array, but first field is some number from 1 to 100 and in seeResponseMatchesJsonType method I must specify field exactly,

code that isn't works for me

```
seeResponseMatchesJsonType(["1"=> [
        "name"=> "Euro",
        "iso"=> "string",
        "sign"=> "string"
    ],...
and that code 100 times or what amount ids I will receive))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your case, I think it's better to use `seeResponseContainsJson` instead of `seeResponseMatchedJsonType`. `seeResponseContainsJson` can be used to validate a part of json is exist in the response.  http://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST#seeResponseContainsJson.

Hope it helps.